# How can I receive file in python-telegram-bot?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I have a problem about file messages in python telegram bot. How can I receive file and read that file ? Or save it.

Comment: what did you try? Where is your code? There is [telegram.Voice.get_file](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.voice.html#telegram.Voice.get_file)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can:

- Register a handler that listens to `Document`
- get `File` object from the update (inside the listener using `get_file`)
- then simply call `.download()` to download the document

Here a sample code to get you started:

```
from telegram.ext import Updater, MessageHandler, Filters

BOT_TOKEN = ' ... '

def downloader(update, context):
    context.bot.get_file(update.message.document).download()

    # writing to a custom file
    with open("custom/file.doc", 'wb') as f:
        context.bot.get_file(update.message.document).download(out=f)


updater = Updater(BOT_TOKEN, use_context=True)

updater.dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.document, downloader))

updater.start_polling()
updater.idle()
```

Comment: Thx bro it download in same dir?

Comment: Yes, but you can pass a custom path. check https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.file.html?#telegram.File.download

Comment: a more question how can i change file name?

Comment: yes, pass a writable file handler as `out`. I've updated the answer to show you how to do it

Comment: i wrote this:` def file_(update:Update,context:CallbackContext):
    with open("file.txt","w") as f:
        context.bot.get_file(update.message.document).download(out=f)`        but it didnt write anything in file.txt

Comment: sorry, it's "wb" not "w". use `open("file.txt","wb")`

Answer (score 6):

Here is some changes for python-telegram-bot v20.

```py
from telegram.ext import Application, MessageHandler, filters


async def downloader(update, context):
    file = await context.bot.get_file(update.message.document)
    await file.download_to_drive('file_name')



def main() -> None:
    application = Application.builder().token('BOT_TOKEN').build()

    application.add_handler(MessageHandler(filters.Document.ALL, downloader))

    application.run_polling()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: And you can filter by filetype too if needed. Here are the docs:  https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/telegram.ext.filters.html