# Download files (spec. images) with telegram bot (python-telegram-bot)

Tags: python, bots, telegram, python-telegram-bot

**Goal**: I'm trying to set up a telegram bot, which downloads pictures that are sent to it.

After doing some manual playing with `requests`, I'd rather like to *use the python-telegram-bot* library. Yet unfortunately most examples outside the docs are written for some Version <20, the official docs are purely written for Versions >20 and unfortunately never cover this topic to an extend which allowed me to write working code. *I dont want to downgrade the version of my lib, I want to understand the current Version (v21.x.x).*

My relevant **current code** looks like this:

```py
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os
import asyncio
import telegram
from telegram import Update
from telegram.ext import Application, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, filters, ContextTypes, ApplicationBuilder
from telegram.ext import InlineQueryHandler, ExtBot

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('TOKEN')


### **Downloader**
async def downloader(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
    logging.DEBUG("in downloader app!")
    new_file = await update.message.effective_attachment[-1].get_file() # [-1] for largest size of photo
    file = await new_file.download_to_drive()
    # file2 = await ExtBot.get_file()
    return file

### **Main**
if __name__ == '__main__':
    application = ApplicationBuilder().token(TOKEN).build()

    downloader_handler = MessageHandler(filters.Document.IMAGE, downloader) #**here are the filters**;
    application.add_handler(downloader_handler)

    #file_handler = MessageHandler(filters.Document.JPG, downloader)   # another try, also Document.ALL 
    #application.add_handler(file_handler)

    application.run_polling()
```

My observations so far:

- when filters set for Document.ALL and i send a pdf-File, it seems to enter the downloader, yet the pdf I'm not able to retrieve the downloaded pdf everytime (it seems its sometimes saving it to a path which is unknown to me)
- when i send an image (jpg), it seems, the downloader is never entered (no debug/print statements)
- I was running in all heaps of Errors, when trying to replace code with snippets from other posts, as it seems most rely on v>20-way of writing this.

To me it seems, this shouldn't be that much hustle...

---

Any help would be highly apprechiated. I don't think, I will be the only one struggling with this after the major overhaul of the library.
Thanks in advance and happy coding to everyone :)

I've tried various stackoverflow-Posts related to this, from all I've read, [this example snippet, specifically designed with v20 syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62253718/how-can-i-receive-file-in-python-telegram-bot) should work. It does for pdfs (see above weird behaviour), but it doesn't for images, which leads me to believe it is some sort of problem related to filters.

**Filters I've tried**:

- `filters.Document.IMAGE`
- `filters.Document.JPG`
- `filters.Document.ALL`

**Questions**:

- which would be the appropriate filter that should work for jpgs?
- What else am I maybe missing here?